# SSL connection on iOS error

Tags: ios, iphone, c, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a server which is written in C++ using OpenSSL. The client that i am using is for iOS. I am using security framework for SSL on iOS. For connecting to the server here is what i do.

1. Create SSL Context
2. Create socket and connect to the server
3. Set certificates
4. Do handshake with the server

SSLHandshake returns -9807 error invalid certificate chain and on the server side the Server still waits on SSL_Accept.

Here is the code

```
-(int)SSLInitClientSocket
{
@try
{

    UINT uitimeout = 40 ; 
    int  inret = 1,err=-1;
    int verify_client = 1;

    m_sslCTX= SSLCreateContext(NULL, kSSLClientSide, kSSLStreamType);
    if (!m_sslCTX)
    {
        //ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        printf("\n ERROR in SSL_CTX_new \n");
        return OS_SOCK_ERROR;
    }

    //Socket is created using socket() function
    if ( OS_SockCreate(&listenerSocket, OS_TCP_SOCK, FALSE) != OS_SOCK_OK)
    {
        CFRelease(m_sslCTX);
        //SSL_CTX_free(m_sslCTX);
        m_sslCTX = NULL;
        return OS_SOCK_ERROR;
    }


    fcntl(listenerSocket, F_SETFD, O_NONBLOCK);

    /* Setting the socket to ignore Nagle Algorithm */
    OS_SockSetOpt(listenerSocket, TCP_OPT_NODELAY, &inret);

    /* Set  Timeout for send and recv */
    OS_SockSetOpt(listenerSocket, TCP_OPT_RCVTIMEOUT, &uitimeout);
    OS_SockSetOpt(listenerSocket, TCP_OPT_SNDTIMEOUT, &uitimeout);
    OS_SockInfo sockinfo;
    strcpy(sockinfo.strName,"172.16.30.209");
    sockinfo.usPort = 5212;
    //connected using connect
    if(OS_SockConnect(listenerSocket, &sockinfo) != OS_SOCK_OK)
    {
        printf("ERROR :: OS_SockConnect \n");
        return OS_SOCK_ERROR;
    }

    OSStatus osstatus;

    osstatus = SSLSetIOFuncs(m_sslCTX, readFromSocket,writeToSocket);
    if(osstatus) {
        return OS_SOCK_ERROR;
    }


    //connectionRef = (SSLConnectionRef)listenerSocket;
    err=SSLSetConnection(m_sslCTX,(SSLConnectionRef)listenerSocket);
    if ((err)==-1)
    {

        return OS_SOCK_ERROR;
    }
    SSLSessionState state;
    SSLGetSessionState(m_sslCTX,  &state);

    osstatus = SSLSetProtocolVersionMin(m_sslCTX,kTLSProtocol1);

    //Set certificates
    if(verify_client == 1)
    {
        CFArrayRef arrcert = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
        NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc]
                            initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/xyz/Desktop/cert/client.p12"];
        CFDataRef myCertData = (CFDataRef)certData;
        const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase};
        const void *values[] = { CFSTR("password")};


        CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

        SecPKCS12Import(myCertData, options, &arrcert);
        CFRelease(options);
        CFDictionaryRef item = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(arrcert, 0);


        SecIdentityRef identity = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(item, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        CFArrayRef certs = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)&identity, 1, NULL);

        err=SSLSetCertificate(m_sslCTX,certs);

    }

    SSLGetSessionState(m_sslCTX,  &state); //Here Session state is Idle


    do
    {
        err = SSLHandshake(m_sslCTX);

    } while (err == errSSLWouldBlock);

    SSLGetSessionState(m_sslCTX,  &state); //here session state is idle and the server is still blocked on SSL_Accept


    return OS_SOCK_OK;
}
@catch(...)
{
    return OS_SOCK_ERROR;
}

}
```

My server code works perfectly fine with c++ and java clients.
I dont know what i am missing.

Comment: i know ios only work with valid certificate not self signed certificate

Comment: i am using a self signed certificate

Comment: @Alireza Aboutalebi: So is there no way to use a self signed certificate on ios?

Comment: i don't think so , there some low price ssl in market you should check it

Comment: i haveve added the certificates to always trust on the machine

Comment: may this could help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a self signed SSL certificate in iOS can be done with a sort of work around but it is HIGHLY recommended not to do this and instead use a trusted certificate. In addition, Apple may reject apps that use self-signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is: `NSOSStatusErrorDomain errSSLXCertChainInvalid`
If you are using `OpenSSL` your could try with:

`$ openssl s_client -connect www.apple.com:443`

`openssl s_client -showcerts -host www.apple.com -port 443`

You can obtain more references about here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/index.html#topic=Sample+Code&section=Resource+Types

I hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

Bringing life to an old thread!

I'm assuming that the code you are using is for something like research or academic work.

Since you're using a self-signed certificate, you can simply add it to the trusted certificates on your iPhone and then try to connect. It should work. However, this method is only for research and should not be done for anything that you wish to publish to the app store.